# Joint evolution using VAR model and pairwise correlation plot in R

Tags: r, vector-autoregression

I have data for three commodities for which I conducted a time series analysis using `VARselect` and `VAR` functions in "vars" package in R.

- How do I describe their joint evolution using the VAR model?
- Also, I know how to generate scatter plots for pairwise correlation but would like to know how to create pair-wise correlation plots using a three-month window for the data?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find [this link](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/2) helpful regarding the interpretation of VAR models.

As windows, you can do this using the `window` function of the `ts{}` package. Create a time series object, and then a window using

```
foo_ts <- ts(data, start = c(2000, 1), end = c(2016, 1))
foo_window <- window(data, start = c(2002, 1), end = c(2005, 1)
```

To make correlograms, one package that makes pretty plots is `corrplot`. Make a dataframe of your time series windows, and try using

```
corrplot.mixed(dataframe)
```

[This](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html) is a great website for that package.

Alternatively, you could use the `corrgram` package, in which case

```
corrgram(dataframe, order=NULL, lower.panel=panel.pts, upper.panel=NULL)
```

might give what you're looking for.

Comment: I have daily data for 10 years so does a  3-month window mean that I need to convert that into quarterly data by setting frequency as 4?

Comment: For daily data over a long period, `frequency = 7`  is a good place to start. You could also make a multiple seasonality ts object, as seen [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/forecasting-with-daily-data/)